# R: Comparing the similarity between a set of graphs?

Tags: r, graph, similarity

Essentially, I'm trying to determine whether there are any graphs that are significantly different from other graphs.

Ideally this would be done through some quantifiable measure of similarity so "significantly different" can be defined by a user. I was thinking about using the area of between two curves as a measure of their difference, though there are probably better, more efficient ways.

I'm not sure how to do this on a larger scale. I'm unsure what I would use as the base of comparison, especially if all graphs are significantly different from one another. Furthermore, I'm not sure how to do this efficiently without needing to compare all of the graphs to one another.

Comment: This question seems better suited to be asked at https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I was thinking that there might be some R package or library that I could use to help with some components of this problem, or something that has already solved this problem, but I will try and post there.

Comment: Even if there were, such a question is also off-topic here, since requests for us to do your searching for you are an specific reason to close a question. You might consider defining "graph" since there are multiple possible interpretations of that work. Are you talking about a network grpah as in pkg:igraph or in the sense of functional data analysis?

Comment: If we are talking about two graphs in the x-y plane, you could just subtract one from the other for all of the domain, and check whether it is smaller than a certain value ( e.g. `x^2` and `x^2 - 1` will give 1, use modulus). However, as others have pointed out, stats.stackexchange.com will be better suited to answer your question.